# JSON.parse: expected property name or '}' JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json

Tengo este String:

```
[
    {'lat':43.4627,'lng':-3.79636,'description':'a'}, 
    {'lat':43.4476,'lng':-3.82948,'description':'b'}, 
    {'lat':43.4228,'lng':-3.82391,'description':'c'}
]
```

Y cuando lo intento validar [aqui](http://json.parser.online.fr/) me da este fallo:

> ```
> SyntaxError: JSON.parse: expected property name or '}' at line 1 
> column 2 of the JSON data
> ```

¿Alquien puede decirme que falla tiene mi String?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El error que comentas

> JSON.parse: expected property name or '}'

o también puedes obtener :

> Expecting 'STRING', '}', got 'undefined'

**Son provocados porque es necesario usar comillas dobles para definir cadenas.**

Esto funcionaría correctamente:

```
[{
        "lat": 43.4627,
        "lng": -3.79636,
        "description": "a"
    },
    {
        "lat": 43.4476,
        "lng": -3.82948,
        "description": "b"
    },
    {
        "lat": 43.4228,
        "lng": -3.82391,
        "description": "c"
    }
]
```

Te recomiendo usar un [validador json](https://jsonlint.com/) en estos casos.

Answer (score 1):

Los nombres de los campos del objeto deben de ir con comillas dobles en vez de simples.

```
[
    {"lat":43.4627,"lng":-3.79636,"description":"a"}, 
    {"lat":43.4476,"lng":-3.82948,"description":"b"}, 
    {"lat":43.4228,"lng":-3.82391,"description":"c"}
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Los nombres de los campos deben ir en comillas dobles en vez de simples.

```
[
    {"lat":43.4627,"lng":-3.79636,"description":"a"}, 
    {"lat":43.4476,"lng":-3.82948,"description":"b"}, 
    {"lat":43.4228,"lng":-3.82391,"description":"c"}
]
```

[image: json]

Según la [documentación oficial](http://json.org/):

> Un valor puede ser una cadena entre **comillas dobles**, o un número, o
>   verdadero o falso o null, o un objeto o una matriz .

Comment: ¿Eres el mismo que plantea la pregunta o eres otro? Las respuestas son casi idénticas al principio.